# creating link on image class in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I was using a template on rails to create a commercial site. It has images on the landing page that I want to direct to other pages depending on the image. it looks like the image below:

[images to be used as links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU6gh.png)

the code for the images is:

```
<div class="top-box">
              <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                 <a href="single.html">
                 <div class="inner_content clearfix">
                    <div class="product_image">
                        <img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">
                       <div class="cart-left">
                            <p class="title">Lorem Ipsum simply</p>
                            <div class="price1">
                              <span class="actual">$12.00</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                     </div>             
                   </div>
                   </a>
                </div>
```

I am a newbie in rails and was asking for assistance please?

Comment: Add an <a> link around images like : `<a href="path_to_redirect"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt=""/></a>`

Comment: Iook like it's already have. can you share a live demo of your code?

Comment: thank you very much. that totally worked. Really appreciate it. how can i make the whole container be a link. not the image alone?

Comment: @jiff the href tag to single brought a routing error

Answer (score 0):

You can use images inside `link_to` method that takes a block.

```
<%= link_to image_path(@image) do %>
  <%= image_tag 'pic3.jpg' %>
<% end %>
```

Also, make sure that you use Rails methods, and not use the plain HTML code to produce images in your application.